# Getting upload progress using Azure Storage in Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-storage, progress

I'm uploading a file in my Android application. The code is pretty simple:

```
    private boolean UploadFile(String fileLocation) {
        try {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fileLocation)) {
                return false;
            }

            File fSrc = new File(fileLocation);

            if (!fSrc.exists()) {
                return false;
            }

            boolean bReturn = AzureManager.init(this);
            if (!bReturn) {
                return false;
            }

            String blobName = fSrc.getName();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fSrc));
            CloudBlobContainer container = AzureManager.getCloudBlobClient().getContainerReference(AzureManager.getContainerName());
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            blob.upload(in, fSrc.length());

            in.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle exception
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I download from Azure,  CloudBlockBlob has a download listener as:

```
blob.setDownloadListener(eventListener);
```

But how can I keep track of the progress when uploading?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?

Comment: Hi. My team mate mad to make some changes in the AzureSDK, I don't really know what he did though but that was the way we could get the percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also finding for the way to do it in Java or Android. But, if you want to make it by your own way, without changing anything on server, you can make it similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175293/how-to-track-progress-of-async-file-upload-to-azure-storage/21182669#21182669). The answer is in C# so you need to find similar method for Java library and update it accordingly.

If you don't want to go on that answer, you can refer the same code from here as well.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), true);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudBlobClient myBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            myBlobClient.SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 1024 * 1024;
            CloudBlobContainer container = myBlobClient.GetContainerReference("adokontajnerneki");
            //container.CreateIfNotExists();
            CloudBlockBlob myBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("cfx.zip");
            var blockSize = 256 * 1024;
            myBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes = blockSize;
            var fileName = @"D:\cfx.zip";
            long bytesToUpload = (new FileInfo(fileName)).Length;
            long fileSize = bytesToUpload;

            if (bytesToUpload < blockSize)
            {
                CancellationToken ca = new CancellationToken();
                var ado = myBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName, FileMode.Open, ca);
                Console.WriteLine(ado.Status); //Does Not Help Much
                ado.ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status = " + t.Status);
                    Console.WriteLine("It is over"); //this is working OK
                });
            }
            else
            {
                List<string> blockIds = new List<string>();
                int index = 1;
                long startPosition = 0;
                long bytesUploaded = 0;
                do
                {
                    var bytesToRead = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesToUpload);
                    var blobContents = new byte[bytesToRead];
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        fs.Position = startPosition;
                        fs.Read(blobContents, 0, (int)bytesToRead);
                    }
                    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                    var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(index.ToString("d6")));
                    Console.WriteLine("Now uploading block # " + index.ToString("d6"));
                    blockIds.Add(blockId);
                    var ado = myBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, new MemoryStream(blobContents), null);
                    ado.ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        bytesUploaded += bytesToRead;
                        bytesToUpload -= bytesToRead;
                        startPosition += bytesToRead;
                        index++;
                        double percentComplete = (double)bytesUploaded / (double)fileSize;
                        Console.WriteLine("Percent complete = " + percentComplete.ToString("P"));
                        mre.Set();
                    });
                    mre.WaitOne();
                }
                while (bytesToUpload > 0);
                Console.WriteLine("Now committing block list");
                var pbl = myBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockIds);
                pbl.ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Blob uploaded completely.");
                });
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This reminds me of the code that was working for us. Thanks for this, if one takes the time and modifies the Azure's library this should work.

Thank you.

Comment: @Lev Welcome. Please let me know if you make similar for android. Please also accept the answer if it works for you. Thank you.

Comment: I don't use Azure any more but I'm almost sure one can make this code work with Azure Android SDK so I accepted your answer. Thanks :)