# How to get callback in andorid after uploading of file is complete using Azure blob storage?

Tags: android, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, kotlin-coroutines

I'm uploading user's profile pic to azure server using Azure blob storage.
This is my code

```
fun uploadImage(path: String, fileInputStream: FileInputStream) =
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString)
            val bobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient()
            val container = bobClient.getContainerReference(storageContainer)
            val blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("$storageContainer.jpg")
            val file = File(path)
            blob.upload(fileInputStream, file.length() )

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

The code is working fine and the image is uploading, when I checked using the URL, but how can I get a callback on success or error of uploading, so that I can perform action on the basis of that.
How can I know when upload finishes or if any error occurred?

Comment: You could refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696914/getting-upload-progress-using-azure-storage-in-android