# How to show a progress bar while uploading data to azure blob in Windows store app

Tags: azure, windows-store-apps, arrays, memorystream, windows-8.1-universal

I have followed the following post to do the upload in chunks to blob

[How to track progress of async file upload to azure storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175293/how-to-track-progress-of-async-file-upload-to-azure-storage/21182669#21182669)

But this is not working in windows store app or windows 8.1 app as there is no support for MemoryStream in win 8.1 app.

Anyhow I have modified the code in the above thread and come up with something like the following

```
        CloudBlobClient myBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();

        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        var file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        string output = string.Empty;

            var fileName = file.Name;


        myBlobClient.SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 1024 * 1024;
        CloudBlobContainer container = myBlobClient.GetContainerReference("files");
        //container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob myBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        var blockSize = 256 * 1024;
        myBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes = blockSize;

        var fileProp = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        var bytesToUpload = fileProp.Size;
        var fileSize = bytesToUpload;



        if (bytesToUpload < Convert.ToUInt64(blockSize))
        {
            CancellationToken ca = new CancellationToken();
            var ado = myBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(file).AsTask();
            await
                            //Console.WriteLine(ado.Status); //Does Not Help Much
                            ado.ContinueWith(t =>
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine("Status = " + t.Status);
                                //Console.WriteLine("It is over"); //this is working OK
                            });
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> blockIds = new List<string>();
            int index = 1;
            ulong startPosition = 0;
            ulong bytesUploaded = 0;
            do
            {
                var bytesToRead = Math.Min(Convert.ToUInt64(blockSize), bytesToUpload);
                var blobContents = new byte[bytesToRead];




                using (Stream fs = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    fs.Position = Convert.ToInt64(startPosition);
                    fs.Read(blobContents, 0, (int)bytesToRead);
                    //var iStream = fs.AsInputStream();



                    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                    var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(index.ToString("d6")));
                    //Console.WriteLine("Now uploading block # " + index.ToString("d6"));
                    blockIds.Add(blockId);
                    var ado = myBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, fs.AsRandomAccessStream(), null).AsTask();
                    await ado.ContinueWith(t =>
                              {
                                  bytesUploaded += bytesToRead;
                                  bytesToUpload -= bytesToRead;
                                  startPosition += bytesToRead;
                                  index++;
                                  double percentComplete = (double)bytesUploaded / (double)fileSize;
                                  output += (percentComplete * 100).ToString() + ",";
                        // AppModel.TasksFormObj.SetProgress(percentComplete * 100);
                        // Console.WriteLine("Percent complete = " + percentComplete.ToString("P"));
                        mre.Set();
                              });

                mre.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            while (bytesToUpload > 0);
            //Console.WriteLine("Now committing block list");
            var pbl = myBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockIds).AsTask();
             pbl.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Blob uploaded completely.");
            });
        }
    }
```

The above code will save the file in blob and the progress is also fine but the saved file in blob is always in 0 bytes . After debugging I found there was an error thrown after var ado = myBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, fs.AsRandomAccessStream(), null).AsTask(); for the last blob transfer as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!--An exception has occurred. For more information please deserialize this message via RequestResult.TranslateFromExceptionMessage.-->
<RequestResult>
  <HTTPStatusCode>400</HTTPStatusCode>
  <HttpStatusMessage>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.</HttpStatusMessage>
  <TargetLocation>Primary</TargetLocation>
  <ServiceRequestID>13633308-0001-0031-060b-7249ea000000</ServiceRequestID>
  <ContentMd5 />
  <Etag />
  <RequestDate>Sun, 28 Feb 2016 10:31:44 GMT</RequestDate>
  <StartTime>Sun, 28 Feb 2016 09:31:43 GMT</StartTime>
  <EndTime>Sun, 28 Feb 2016 09:31:44 GMT</EndTime>
  <Error>
    <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
    <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:13633308-0001-0031-060b-7249ea000000
Time:2016-02-28T09:34:18.3545085Z</Message>
    <HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName>
    <HeaderValue>0</HeaderValue>
  </Error>
  <ExceptionInfo>
    <Type>StorageException</Type>
    <HResult>-2147467259</HResult>
    <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.</Message>
    <Source>Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage</Source>
    <StackTrace>   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.&lt;ExecuteAsyncInternal&gt;d__c`1.MoveNext()</StackTrace>
  </ExceptionInfo>
</RequestResult>
```

Then on the last commit the error thrown after  myBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockIds) as  **The specified block list is invalid**

So please someone help me to to figure out where I am doing wrong or what is the possible solution to make it work 100%.

Comment: I just tried to create a Windows Store App in Visual Studio 2013 and MemoryStream was available to me. This is what I tried to create: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZfQH.png.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsTask()` like this.

```
 CancellationTokenSource _cts;

 _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();//<--In Constructor 

 var progress = new Progress<double>(TranscodeProgress); 
 await var ado = myBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(file).AsTask(_cts.Token, progress);
```