# Azure storage and Oracle Blob content

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am converting Oracle blob content in to byte stream and uploading the contents to azure cloud storage. Is there any way i can cross check whether the uploaded files to the storage are proper or not corrupted.
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

@Bala,
As far as I known, we can check whether uploaded files are success via these methods:

1. After uploaded file, we can get the blob file length property and compare with the original file size.

   ```
   blob.FetchAttributes();
   ```

   bool success = blob.Properties.Length == length;
2. Another approach is that we can split files into chunks and upload those chunks asynchronously using `PutBlockAsync` method. We can view the uploading progress if you can create a progress bar based this methods and chunks size. I recommend you refer to this post about how to use this methods:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/21182669/4836342 or this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2010/11/03/uploading-a-blob-to-azure-storage-with-progress-bar-and-variable-upload-block-size/).